# Lock a Grid in Show UI

Tags: wpf, powershell, codeplex

Can Any one help me on how to lock the grid in showui module in powershell??

Im creating a application which uses a grid

Grid -ControlName 'Show-Demo' -Columns Auto,* -Rows 9 -MinHeight 500 -MaxHeight 500 -MinWidth 500 -MaxWidth 500 {

} -Show

When i run this i'am able to get a grid view but the size is not locked, im still able to resize the grid with my mouse, i wanted to avoid that and permanently lock it to MAX and MIN height and width of 500

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The grid is fixed size already. Try setting `-Background Blue` on the grid and then resize, you'll see what I mean.

What you want is to make the *Window* not resizable.  For that, you'll have to actually specify the Window, instead of just using -Show on the grid:

```
Window { 
    Grid -ControlName 'Show-Demo' -Columns Auto,* -Rows 9 {
       ...
    }
}  -MinHeight 500 -MaxHeight 500 -MinWidth 500 -MaxWidth 500 -Show
```